# 1980s story with strange deadly creatures send to a different planet

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to find a book I've read a while ago, 80s to be more exact hence my assumption that it was published somewhere between 70s and 80s.

I remember that there were some strange deadly creatures that once caught were sent to a different planet. The name of that planet eludes me but I do remember that it had number 3 in it.

I also  remember that the book cover had a picture which included flying manta rays and behind them there was some sort of a space ship or space colony.

EDIT: 
The book was not part of a trilogy.

I just remembered that there was a search for some chemical. Antitoxin maybe?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it doesn't match much of the description.... but if it's been almost 30 years, you may have merged a few stories mentally.. I do it all the time..

The description of Flying Manta Rays immediately made me think of the '[Of Man and Manta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Of_man_and_manta)' series by Piers Anthony, the three volumes of which were originally published in 1968, 1970 and 1975, receptively.

Do any of these look familiar?

[image: Of Man and Manta (Omnibus)][image: Omnivore v3][image: Omnivore v2][image: Omnivore v1]

Comment: The manta ray from the cover of "Omnivore" looks familiar but I do remember the space craft of some sort behind the manta ray. I do also think that you got miss-guided by manta rays since I don't remember them in the story just on the cover of the book. And I am pretty sure it was a stand alone novel rather than part of a trilogy.

Comment: :)  K; it was too obvious not to give it a shot :)